# Declare a list of element from different classes

Tags: java, list, wildcard

I have a class, which extends another class (e.g. `dog` extends `animal`).
If I want to declare a list, which can contain dog as well as animal, how can i declare this?

I have declared my list as below (with wildcard), but this is not recommended by sonar

```java
List <?>
```

Comment: Note that `List<dog>` is not the same as `List<animal>`. If you have a method whose parameter is `List<animal>` you cannot call that method with `List<dog>`. That's why there is the [PECS](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics-pecs) rule. Can you [edit] your question and provide more context? Why do you need a `List` that contains both `dog` and `animal`? Of-course you can always do: `new ArrayList<animal>().add(new dog());` but is that a preferable option?

Comment: QTT, have you read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using generics here (including the ? wildcard) would be a mistake. This can be done simply by creating a list of `Animals`:

```java
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Because `Dog` extends `Animal` it is an `Animal`, and as such can be an element in the List of `Animals`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

because **Dog** is an **Animal** when **Dog** extends **Animal**. But you only use attributes and function from **Animal** or function from **Dog** which is override a function from **Animal**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).